# What is connection string for Go GORM with SQL Server in case Windows Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

With username/password authenticatio

```golang
package postgres

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlserver"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code  string
    Price uint
}

func Main() {
    dsn := "sqlserver://sa:12345678@localhost:1433?database=gorm"
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    // Migrate the schema.
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
    // Create.
    db.Create(&Product{Code: "D42", Price: 100})
    // Read.
    var product Product
    db.First(&product, 1)                 // Find product with integer primary key.
    db.First(&product, "code = ?", "D42") // Find product with code D42.
    // Update - update product's price to 200.
    db.Model(&product).Update("Price", 200)
    // Update - update multiple fields.
    db.Model(&product).Updates(Product{Price: 200, Code: "F42"}) // non-zero fields.
    db.Model(&product).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"Price": 200, "Code": "F42"})
    // Delete - delete product.
    db.Delete(&product, 1)
}
```

What is connection string for Go GORM with SQL Server in case Windows Authentication? Please guide me change this link

```
"sqlserver://sa:12345678@localhost:1433?database=gorm"
```

Related link https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

```
connectring_String := "sqlserver://:@localhost:1433?database=gorm"
```

See https://youtu.be/9JvnXcSYQTU?t=2

Answer (score 0):

for "sqlserver://sa:12345678@localhost:1433?database=gorm"

- sqlserver:// : means use Microsoft SQL Server database
- sa : your db server name
- 123456 : your db password
- localhost:1443 : db ip and port
- database=xxx : use database xxx